# How to numprint result of command?

Tags: macros

Faulty code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{numprint}

\newcommand{\ratio}{%
  \FPdiv\result{\x}{\y}%
  \FPround\result\result{2}%
  \result%
}

\begin{document}
\FPset\x{2}
\FPset\y{3}
\numprint{\ratio}
\end{document}
```

LaTeX complains:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   \next ->\@nil
>
> l.14 \numprint{\ratio}

*How do I evaluate `\ratio` and print it with `\numprint`?*

Comment: `\numprint` wants to see a number, not the instructions for producing it. Can you show a more realisting situation?

Comment: @egreg I have a macro that outputs a value which depends on previously defined variables.

Comment: easier syntax is made possible if the computations are done expandably; [egreg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) has now provided an `l3fp` approach. Using [xintfrac](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint), `\numprint{\xintRound {2}{\xintDiv\x\y}}`. And with [xintexpr](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint) `\numprint{\xinttheexpr round(\x/\y,2)\relax}`. I did not make an answer because you might need functions such as `sin` or `cos` which are not at this time yet in `xintexpr`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `\numprint` macro needs to be fed with a string of characters, not with the instructions to produce it. With `fp`, these instructions involve assignments, while `\numprint` is only able to process a control sequence that just expands to a number in the proper format. So the string has to be produced in advance.
(Thanks to jfbu for noticing that macros can be used in the argument to `\numprint`, so long as they expand to strings with the proper format.)

I suggest you to define a new command that takes as argument an FP expression, possibly in a macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{numprint}

\newcommand{\numprintexpr}[2][\result]{%
  #2\relax\numprint{#1}}

\newcommand{\ratio}{%
  \FPdiv\result{\x}{\y}%
  \FPround\result\result{2}%
}

\begin{document}

\FPset\x{2}
\FPset\y{3}
\numprintexpr{\ratio}

\numprintexpr[\foo]{%
  \FPset\x{24}%
  \FPset\y{19}%
  \FPdiv\foo{\x}{\y}%
  \FPround\foo\foo{2}
}

\end{document}
```

The optional argument (default `\result`) tells `\numprintexpr` what control sequence stores the final result.

[image]

---

A different implementation using the fixed point facilities of `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{numprint}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\fpeval}{m}
 {
  \fp_eval:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\fpset}{mm}
 {
  \fp_zero_new:N #1
  \fp_set:Nn #1 { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \feklee_numprint:n #1
 {
  \numprint { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\numprintexpr}{m}
 {
  \feklee_numprint:n { \fp_eval:n { #1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\ratio}{round(\x/\y,2)}

\begin{document}

\fpset\x{2}
\fpset\y{3}
\numprintexpr{\ratio}

\numprintexpr{round(pi/4,8)}

\end{document}
```

The syntax is different, but it's even easier than with `fp`.

[image]

Comment: Is there no way to evaluate `\ratio` and print it with `\numprint` without knowing the internals of the `\ratio` command?

Comment: @feklee No, but with the suggested `\numprintexpr` command you *don't* need to know the internals, other than the scratch macro you use for storing the result: `\numprint` wants to see a string of characters, not the instructions for producing it. It would be different if you used the `l3fp` macros, that are expandable.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Perhaps you want to add this information to your answer.

Comment: @feklee Check the new implementation; I know it requires changing the syntax for expressions, but I believe it's better in the long run.

Comment: @egreg `\numprint` accepts completely expandable material: it is not a requirement that the input is a string of character, it may be a macro  `\x` as long  as `\x` expands to a string of characters in an acceptable format. (I suspect this is what you meant but beginners may have taken your sentence literally).

Comment: @jfbu Thanks for telling me about this; actually I didn't check for this property; it simplifies the macros I defined.

Comment: I had used that in the comment I made a few days back to the OP's question...

Answer (score 6):

pass the x/y values into the macro itself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{numprint}

\newcommand\ratio[3]{%
  \FPdiv#3{#1}{#2}%
  \FPround{#3}{4}{4}}

\begin{document}
\ratio{2}{3}\result
\result

\numprint{\result}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You modified `\ratio`. That's an approach. However, I am asking for a solution to *evaluate `\ratio`* and then print the result using `\numprint`.

Answer (score 2):

You asked for a solution which keeps your original `\ratio` and then prints the result using `\numprint`. Here is how to do it:

[update: edited to avoid global assignments]

[update2: added `\fFPedef` macro which is necessary if one wants to go into the direction indicated at the bottom of this answer]

[update3: removed some superfluous `\expandafter`'s]

[update4: fixed typo above (`\fFPedef` above was in my earlier choice `\fFPset`) just to move this up the list and get a chance to gather more upvotes `:)` ]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{numprint}

% ORIGINAL \ratio
% by convention its result is in ... \result
\newcommand{\ratio}{%
  \FPdiv\result{\x}{\y}%
  \FPround\result\result{2}%
  \result%
}

% WRAPPER to \numprint
% Must be applied to things like \ratio which compute a \result
\def\FPnumprint #1{% 
    \setbox0 \hbox{\def\result{#1}#1\expandafter}\expandafter
    \numprint\expandafter {\result}}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
\FPset\x{2}
\FPset\y{3}

% works
\FPnumprint {\ratio}

\newcommand{\stuff}{\FPeval\result {(\x)*(\y)+(\x)^(\y)}}

% works also

\FPnumprint {\stuff}

\end{document}
```

Output:

> [image: numprint result]

By the way one can use this kind of technique to transform all commands of `fp.sty` into nestable entities: (I use  `fFP@` prefix to mean *functional form of an fp command*)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{numprint}

% ORIGINAL \ratio
% by convention its result is in ... \result
\newcommand{\ratio}{%
  \FPdiv\result{\x}{\y}%
  \FPround\result\result{2}%
  \result%
}

% WRAPPER to \numprint
% Must be applied to things like \ratio which compute a \result
\def\FPnumprint #1{% 
    \setbox0 \hbox{\def\result{#1}#1\expandafter}\expandafter
    \numprint\expandafter {\result}}

\makeatletter
\def\fFPadd #1#2{%
  \setbox0 \hbox{\def\fFP@result{#1}#1\expandafter}%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\fFP@tmpa\expandafter{\fFP@result}%
  \setbox0 \hbox{\def\fFP@result{#2}#2\expandafter}%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\fFP@tmpb\expandafter{\fFP@result}%
  \FPadd\fFP@result \fFP@tmpa\fFP@tmpb 
  \fFP@result
}

\def\fFPmul #1#2{%
  \setbox0 \hbox{\def\fFP@result{#1}#1\expandafter}%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\fFP@tmpa\expandafter{\fFP@result}%
  \setbox0 \hbox{\def\fFP@result{#2}#2\expandafter}%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\fFP@tmpb\expandafter{\fFP@result}%
  \FPmul\fFP@result \fFP@tmpa\fFP@tmpb 
  \fFP@result
}

\def\fFPround #1#2{%
  \setbox0 \hbox{\def\fFP@result{#1}#1\expandafter}%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\fFP@tmpa\expandafter{\fFP@result}%
  \setbox0 \hbox{\def\fFP@result{#2}#2\expandafter}%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\fFP@tmpb\expandafter{\fFP@result}%
  \FPround\fFP@tmpb\fFP@tmpb {0}%
  \FPround\fFP@result \fFP@tmpa\fFP@tmpb
  \fFP@result
}

\def\fFPnumprint #1{%
    \setbox0 \hbox {\def\fFP@result {#1}#1\expandafter}%
    \expandafter\numprint\expandafter{\fFP@result}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\FPset\x{2}
\FPset\y{3}

% works
\FPnumprint {\ratio}

\newcommand{\stuff}{\FPeval\result {(\x)*(\y)+(\x)^(\y)}}

% works also
\FPnumprint {\stuff}

\fFPadd {\fFPmul{2}{7}}{\fFPmul{3}{7}}


\fFPround {\fFPadd{\fFPmul {3.21267}{5.277282}}{16.8927287}}{2}

\fFPround {\fFPadd{\fFPmul {3.21267}{5.277282}}{16.8927287}}{\fFPadd {1}{3}}

% !!! ATTENTION !!!
% HERE We USE \fFPnumprint as we know the "result" is in "\fFP@result" not in
% "\result"

\fFPnumprint {\fFPround {\fFPadd{\fFPmul
      {3.21267}{5.277282}}{16.8927287}}{\fFPadd {1}{3}}}

\end{document}
```

Output:

> [image: fFP in action]

Perhaps some package could be made out of this starting point ... as `fp` is quite in use.

---

One needs in addition to the above a macro of the following type:

```
\makeatletter

\def\fFPedef #1#2{%
    \setbox0 \hbox{\def\fFP@result{#2}#2\expandafter}%
    \expandafter\edef\expandafter#1\expandafter{\fFP@result}%
}

\makeatother

\ttfamily

\fFPedef\x {\fFPmul{3.142627627}{\fFPadd{6.75272872}{7.832298292}}}
\meaning\x
```

Output:

> [image: fFPedef]

The big difference is that as we can see here, these things are nestable.

Comment: You still need to know what the scratch macro is called; it may not be `\result`, for instance if you need two computations in parallel.

Comment: @egreg The name of the scratch macro could be an optional argument defaulting to `\result`. In the second part of the answer I switch to `\fFP@result`.

Comment: @egreg you mean two computations _inside_ the `\numprint`?

Comment: The optional argument is what I used, too. Multiple computations may be needed, using different storage macros; of course only one will store the final result and one can arrange for it to be named `\result`.

Comment: @egreg one needs indeed  an additional macro with the syntax `\fFPprint\x{...}` which will define `\x` to expand to the result of the (nested) computations; the difference with the original syntax of `fp` being that here we can nest things.

Answer (score 2):

There is already several answers to this question, but it seems that nobody suggested to use `\edef`.  Knowing about this might be useful for you in other situations, so let me describe this alternative solution.

The `\edef` primitive is similar to `\def` but will expand the replacement text of the macro being defined. Here is how to rewrite your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{numprint}

\newcommand{\ratio}{%
  \FPdiv\result{\x}{\y}%
  \FPround\result\result{2}%
}

\begin{document}
\FPset\x{2}
\FPset\y{3}
\begingroup
  \ratio
  \edef\next{\noexpand\numprint{\result}%
  \expandafter
\endgroup
\next
\end{document}
```

See that *computation* and *usage* are now separated. The job of `\ratio` is limited to compute the ratio and store this in a macro.

TeX works very differently than a classical programming language where you can compose functions as you did. Indeed, it is a macro language, based on expanding and rewriting. So if you write

```
\numprint{\ratio}
```

you have *absolutley* no control over how the tokens produced by `\ratio` will be interpreted.  It is easier to produce a `\next` macro whose replacement text is `\numprint{0.67}` as I did in my suggestion. Note that the whole `\begingroup…\next` snippet is actually replaced by `\numprint{0.67}` during processing.

If you are learning programming TeX, you should consider learning these methods based on `\edef`, `\expandafter`, `\noexpand` and registers.

Comment: In what does this differ from my answer?

Comment: In what is this similar to your answer? It is not obvious to me so it will probably not be for the casual reader.

Comment: I'm doing `\ratio\numprint{\result}` which is essentially the same, except for the group.

Comment: As I stated it in my answer, I think that suggesting the use of `\edef` might be a useful addition for somebody experimenting with or learning TeX's programming system.